# Flutter FutureBuilder widget dynamic list lenght

Tags: listview, flutter, builder

I am trying to make dynamic ListView.builder in FutureBuilder widget but can't get lenght of list which comes from AsyncSnapshot snapshot. I've tried `itemCount: snapshot.data.lenght` but it did not work.  Here is my code

```
class FlutterDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  final QuoteStorage storage;

  FlutterDemo({Key key, @required this.storage}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Scrapy on flutter')),
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder(
            future: storage.getQuotes(),
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<Quotes> snapshot) {
              return snapshot.hasData ? ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.lenght,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final quotes = snapshot.data;
                  return Card(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Text(quotes.items[index].quote),
                      ));
                },
              )
                  : const CircularProgressIndicator();
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Data comes from class Quotes:

```
class Quotes extends Items {
  @override
  final List<Quote> items;
  Quotes({
    this.items,
  });

  factory Quotes.fromJson(String str) => Quotes.fromMap(json.decode(str));
  factory Quotes.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Quotes(
        items: json["items"] == null
            ? null
            : List<Quote>.from(json["items"].map((x) => Quote.fromMap(x))),
      );
}
```

And quotes storage class used to build future:

```
class QuoteStorage {
  // ...
  // ...
  Future<Quotes> getQuotes() async {
    final file = await _localFile;
    final contents = await file.readAsString();
    return Quotes.fromJson(contents);
  }
}
```

App is crashing if I don't provide itemCount which is dynamic (fetch from url).
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error because you spelt `length` wrong.

You can fix this by correcting the spelling of `length`. 
Replace your `FlutterDemo` class with the code below

It works perfectly fine.

```
class FlutterDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  final QuoteStorage storage;

  FlutterDemo({Key key, @required this.storage}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Scrapy on flutter')),
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder(
            future: storage.getQuotes(),
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<Quotes> snapshot) {
              return snapshot.hasData ? ListView.builder(
                // current the spelling of length here
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final quotes = snapshot.data;
                  return Card(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Text(quotes.items[index].quote),
                      ));
                },
              )
                  : const CircularProgressIndicator();
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it here, I've figured out that need to use `itemCount: snapshot.data.items.length`  bacause `items` is list I can get count from.